# Ionic Menu (ion-menu) in Angular - Disable Backdrop

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, menu

Ionic Menu (ion-menu) in Angular - Disable Backdrop

Hello, I am wondering if there is a way to disable the backdrop when using an ion-menu?

I would like to keep the page functional while the menu is open.

I'm looking to do something similar to what is on the O365 admin interface.

[image: O365 Side View]

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but maybe this would help : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/split-pane

Comment: I was told it isn't very easy to pass data to a split-pane. But I'm trying to do something like what is on the O365 admin page where you have a list of users and when you click a user it shows their details in a side view on the right. Or when you add a user a form is opened in a side view on the right. I added an image in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to create with css a div that's opaque, then using an *ngIf show it when you activate the menu. Hope that could help :P